# CSS: Overflow-x, display:flex issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, flexbox

I have done already 2 questions related with the issue I'm having. But here I have created a better example. Please see below. The boxes are being loaded by Angular ng-bind.

Please see the following code pen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LRPwZP

As well, I'm including the same snippet into stackoverflow, but be aware that it's not possible to resize the resolution, therefore, the example might not be useful.

**It's very important to notice the desired behaviour:**

1. Every box has the same width (of 700px in the real case)
2. Box #1 is desired to be at the top left.
3. Box #2 is desired to be at the right of the box #1 only if there's enough space.
4. Box #3 if still screen has space, goes at the right of box #2.
5. Now, assuming there's no longer space at the right, of box #3
6. Box #4, falls at the bottom of box #1.
7. Box #5, goes directly at the bottom of the box #2.
8. Box #6, goes directly at the bottom of the box #3.
9. so on...
10. Boxes are loaded using angular ng-bind, and are dynamic.

**I can't use the following options:**

**(1)**

```
:nth-child(odd) { float: left; }
:nth-child(even) { float: right; }
```

**Reason:** useless and fails when you need more than 2 columns.

**(2)** I'm aware of AngularJS Masonry, I don't want to increase the loading time, and I want to accomplish this using only CSS.

**For references:**

- No CSS frameworks are being use.
- Pure "Vainilla" JS is being use - occasionally.
- AngularJS is heavy used.

**Previous questions, same issue:**

- [CSS multiple different height float left elements arranged in 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246427/css-multiple-different-height-float-left-elements-arranged-in-2-columns?noredirect=1#comment65829597_39246427)
- [Flex, AngularJS + Masonry, akoenig/angular-deckgrid and more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260023/css-overflow-x-on-displayflex/39260083?noredirect=1#comment65856919_39260083)

Kind regards,
Chris,

Comment: Another better dupe target - http://stackoverflow.com/q/8470070/2930477

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a few days testing Masonry, Isotope, and a few different angular and JQuery modules... most of them requiring lots of workarounds just to function properly... and after trying as well different ng-directives and modules made by users to make something like masonry in angular, without using it. I found the solution: AngularMaterial. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options Might be obvious, but takes time to understand what you're looking for sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using flex?

```css
ul{
  background-color: #ffeb00;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: space-around;
}
li{
  padding: 35px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #8056ff;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Box 1</li>
  <li>Box 2</li>
  <li>Box 3</li>
  <li>Box 4</li>
  <li>Box 5</li>
  <li>Box 6</li>
</ul>
```